# Template ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the code in my view for users ratings display:

```
<div class="leftBlock">
    <div class="leftBlockHead">
        <div class="textHead">
            <b>Users rating</b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftBlockContent">
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <div class="list">
                @user.Login @user.Rating
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I use the same html structure for some other blocks. So I don't want to repeat this code, I need some kind of template which will take block title and @foreach as arguments. What are the ways to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally used [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).

Here is my partial view:

```
@model LeftColumnBlockViewModel

<div class="levo_blok1">
    <div class="levo_blok1_head">
        <div class="text_head">
            @Model.Title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="levo_blok1_content">
        @Model.Content(null)
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the view model for it:

```
public class LeftColumnBlockViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Func<dynamic, object> Content { get; set; }

        public LeftColumnBlockViewModel(string title, Func<dynamic, object> content)
        {
            Title = title;
            Content = content;
        }
    }
```

and here is the usage:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views._LeftColumnBlock, 
              new LeftColumnBlockViewModel(
                  Battles.CurrentBattles, 
                  @<text>
                    @foreach (var currentBattle in Model.CurrentBattlesViewModels) 
                    { 
                        <div class="list">
                            @currentBattle.Budget / @currentBattle.BetLimit% / @currentBattle.StartDate-@currentBattle.EndDate
                        </div> 
                    }
                  </text>))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at creating HTMLHelper class extension methods to do such rendering.
You can also use the HTMLHelper RenderPartial method. For this you need to define

- A separate view class.
- Have a model associated with it. Call the
- RenderPartial extension where ever this view needs to be render.

Comment: but how can I pass foreach statement to partial view?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go ahead and write a custom html helper to do that...It would look something like

```
@helper YourHelper(Model model){
**DO YOUR FOREACH STUFF IN HERE**
<div class="leftBlock">
    <div class="leftBlockHead">
        <div class="textHead">
            <b>model.Title</b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftBlockContent">
        @Html.Raw(model.Content)
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and then you'd use it..@YourHelper(model)

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx